# Error: 'The name printForm1 does not exist in the current context' Why is this?

Tags: c#

Hi i got this code from MSDN. I can't figure out the problem, i hope you can help. The error is located with the two lines that have the words printForm1 in. My form is actually called Form1, so i cannot see the problem.

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    private Bitmap memoryImage;
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btncustCont.Visible = false; 
        btnprintCost.Visible = false;
        btnpdfCont.Visible = false;
        btnpdfBrochureCont.Visible = false;
        btnpaperCont.Visible = false;
        btnduplicateCont.Visible = false;
        btntypeCont.Visible = false;
        btnCalcCost.Visible = false;
        btnprintCost.Visible = false;

        Application.DoEvents();
        CaptureScreen();
        printForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printForm1.Print();

        btncustCont.Visible = true; 
        btnprintCost.Visible = true;
        btnpdfCont.Visible = true;
        btnpdfBrochureCont.Visible = true;
        btnpaperCont.Visible = true;
        btnduplicateCont.Visible = true;
        btntypeCont.Visible = true;
        btnCalcCost.Visible = true;
        btnprintCost.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: You're never declaring printForm1

Comment: so what would i declare printForm1 as, as it is the name of my form already

Comment: Does printForm1 even exist? Maybe in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how this MSDN article declares the printDocument1 at the top of the class:

```
private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6he9hz8c(v=vs.100).aspx

You'd want to do the same thing, just with printForm1

Comment: YES! Thank you! That was my last error and i can finally move on in my project!

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem, this will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can think of:

If I'm reading it right, `printForm1` is an instance of a PrintDocument object. Sorry If I'm not giving you enough credit here but are you sure printForm1 is actually declared anywhere?

Otherwise, make sure your (codeBehind).cs file actually inherits the page that has this element on it.

Comment: Nope, you're giving me all the credit i deserve haha. This is my first program i've ever created in C# so that was the problem. They are similar but i'm more of a VB type of guy

Comment: Yeah, I'm used to the syntax because I learned to program in C++ but instantiation in C-style syntax languages can take getting used to if you've never dealt with it before.